# How do I send a TradingView Alert to discord using alert() in my pinescript code not the message part

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

[image: ![alert message]]

My alert message from Tradingview isn't being sent to Discord. I have attached a screen image showing how my image looks.  My discord channel is blank.

I think the issue is the } isn't at the end of the message, but the code I am using does have it at the end.

```
bullCondition_Label            = "TF Period1: " + TF1 + " " + syminfo.ticker + '\n' + 'Background Change to Green \n'

if barstate.islast
    for i = 0 to 19
        LabelAdd = array.get(s_arr, i) + ' Price:' + str.tostring(array.get(price_arr, i), '#.#') + '\n'
        bullCondition_Label            := array.get(bullCond_arr, i)       ? bullCondition_Label            + LabelAdd : bullCondition_Label

if bullCondition
    alert_message1= "{\"content\":\"" + '\n'+ bullCondition_Label + "\"}"
    alert(alert_message1, alert.freq_once_per_bar_close)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is complicated, cause of hidden bugs/features.

You are using inverted comma (`'`) and quotation marks (`"`) to declare text which confuses me at least. I recommend using one type only to declare your text, and use `str.format()` for multiple parts strings.

There are some rare cases when using an inverted comma followed by some other escape command (like curly brackets or a backslash) it will result in not displaying it all.

On the other hand, when using inverted comma the text inside it can have quotation marks without been seen as command. But when using quotation marks it cause all commands inside to execute unless a backslash is in front of them.

Anyway I would recommend using quotation marks all the time
and use the backslash to put any escape command into text.
There is one exception, you need two inverted comma to display one inverted comma,
inside text declared via quotation marks.

---

you should also double check the webhook and you have to use `ALT+A` to set up the alarm, in the case of using `alert()`.

Comment: Hi Mario, thank you for responding.  Where woudl i use the str.format()?  would I use it here? alert_message1= "{\"content\":\"" + '\n'+ bullCondition_Label + "\"}"?

Comment: @mgoblue33 I use it anywhere when changing values into string and doesn't need to be a const variable.